# Vertx Web API Service File uploading using OpenAPI3RouterFactory and EventBus

Tags: java, vert.x

I am trying to upload file with other related data in Rest API using Vert.x Web API Contract defining service interface with OpenAPI operations definition as follows:-

```
/api/pets/{petId}/uploadImage:
post:
  summary: upload file for pet
  operationId: savePetPicture
  x-vertx-event-bus: "petstore_manager.myapp"
  parameters:
    - name: petId
      in: path
      required: true
      description: The id of the pet
      schema:
        type: string
  requestBody:
    description: image to be used as pet picture
    content:
      multipart/form-data:
        schema:
          type: object
          properties:
            profileImage:
              type: string
              format: binary
            name:
              type: string
```

I have a service interface PetStoreManagerService where I have defined methods to handle the operations for this resource.

```
@WebApiServiceGen
public interface PetStoreManagerService {
    void savePetPicture(PetImage body, String petId, OperationRequest operationRequest,
                      Handler<AsyncResult<OperationResponse>> handler);
}
```

and Model class is defined as follows

```
@DataObject(generateConverter = true, publicConverter = false)
public class PetImage {
  String name;
  Buffer profileImage;
}
```

I have followed this tutorial in my project. [vertx-web-api-service tutorial](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-service/java/#_mount_to_router_factory)
My question is what should be the type of profileImage in this PetImage class? I am getting null for the requestBody in my service implementation class.

I have found some post where the operation is handled in MainVerticle class as

```
routerFactory.addHandlerByOperationId("savePetPicture",  routingContext -> {
Set<FileUpload> fileUploadSet = routingContext.fileUploads();
Iterator<FileUpload> fileUploadIterator = fileUploadSet.iterator();
// ...
```

I was wondering if this could be handled in service class, routing the request to PetStoreManagerService implementation class as it is shown in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event Bus is not designed to handle large payloads (mostly because it lacks byte streaming), hence you should not try to perform file uploads through it.

There are a bunch of thread on vert.x mailing list I encourage you to read that explains the issue:

- https://groups.google.com/g/vertx/c/vw-wnqK_ckE/m/amqEBm0aAQAJ
- https://groups.google.com/g/vertx/c/AnZ0ZiSgiqQ/m/lb7f7r1XDAAJ
- https://groups.google.com/g/vertx/c/42mJE3FqqUA

If you need to implement an OpenAPI operation that handles file uploads, you should implement it using the usual Vert.x Web Handler mounted as explained [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-api-contract/java/#_mount_the_handlers) and retrieve the file uploads as explained [here](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_handling_file_uploads)